# How to Delete all contents of a "File with no extension"  using windows batch Command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to delete the contents of a file which has "FIlE" as extension i.e with no extension.
I know how to  delete the contents of a Text file, but not about the file which has "File" as extension.

I would appreciate your efforts.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Del *.` in batch file to remove files with no extension.

use `Dir /A-D *.` to list down all files with no extension.

Use following command to clear the contents of a file

```
findstr "Any data that is not available in origfilename" origfilename > origfilename
```

Comment: +1 - While I don't think your `findstr` is the best way to clear a file, I didn't know about `*.`, which is really useful!

Comment: `del *.` does not work. Just gives the usual file not found error.

Comment: @Deleet it will work if you use cmd, as opposed to powershell

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo. 2>file.
```

It will basically overwrite the file with nothing, achieving the same goal as removing all the contents. Just replace `file.` with your file. To specify no extension just don't put anything after the `.`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about

*`del /s "*."`*

Worked well on the tests I did on windows 10.   Test it of course in a safe directory.  You can of course put this into a batch.  I do one for cleaning out annoying left overs like .txt with something like:

```
echo off

del /s D:\FILES\completed\*.nfo

del /s D:\FILES\completed\*.wflow

del /s D:\FILES\completed\*.workflow

del /s "D:\FILES\completed\*."

echo complete

echo on
```

Will delete all files in the main directory and all sub directories.
Quotes were required as it would not work without them.   Did not try it with 3 deep extenstions.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy nul YourFIlE
copy /y nul YourFIlE
```

In case you wonder, `NUL` is a special name (like `/dev/null` on UNIX), just as `CON` (which is the console). I think this is the best way to clear the contents. The file will then have 0 bytes in it. An `echo` plus output redirection will write one line to the file, so it does not completely clear the contents.

Answer (score 0):

> del *.

will do but you need to call it from the regular command prompt, not from powershell.