# Delete files without filetype from command line

Tags: windows, ubuntu, command-prompt

So i have an image collection system that currently has dumped around 40k+ images. In order for sound processing of said images to happen, i need to "clean up" the dump directory. What i need is a script to remove all images that dont have a filetype. Here is a sample of my dump dir:

[image: sample of my dump dir]

I have tried following the instructions given in this Stack Post:

[How to Delete all contents of a "File with no extension"  using windows batch Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635840/how-to-delete-all-contents-of-a-file-with-no-extension-using-windows-batch-co)

However, this does not work as it relies on the file having a period in its name, regardless of having a (or no) file extension. I obviously cant execute:
 "del *" as that will delete all the images.

So how could I achieve a mass delete of this type of file? If there is a linux alternative let me know as i can move the dumps to my 14.04 Ubuntu server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you actually try the solution in the linked question?  It works for me.  (In Windows, a file without a dot in the name has an implicit dot at the end.)

Comment: Hah, it wasnt working for me before, but now it is for some reason - must have been doing somethign wrong!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu I would use

```
rm !(*.*)
```

It should remove all files without extension.

---

If you want to delete all files which are not .jpg or .JPG

```
rm !(*.jpg|*.JPG)
```

Comment: A 'Nix Oriented solution is what i was looking for! Thankyou very muchly